# FIlter is not searching in my app

Tags: jquery, html, touch, jquery-mobile

In my App , I have a filter, It needs to search for two listviews. please where i did wrong. i am not getting results of second listview.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Quickshops</li>
        <li><a href="#">Yours previous orders</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Your Shopping Lists</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Your Favorites</a></li>

    </ul>

    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Whats Good</li>
        <li><a href="">Configuring defaults</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Events</a></li>

        <li><a href="">Methods &amp; Utilities</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Responsive Layout</a></li> 
        <li><a href="">Theme framework</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: please be specific what you want?i didn't get anything from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to set  `data-filter="true"` on the second one too!

Answer (score 0):

chenge `data-inset="true"` it to `data-filter="true"` in your second listView